# How are akka actors implemented on underlying threads?

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, actor

Given an execution context and a thread pool, how are akka/scala actors scheduled/implemented on that?

Comment: The akka documentation already contains a clear explanation.

Answer (score 33):

I was confused about this topic for a long time. I assumed that there is some relation between threads and actors. For each actor, there is a thread that hosts it, so I was thinking. Probably there are several actors for each thread that work in cooperative multitasking mode.

Documentation is focused on usage and covers internal architecture lightly. You just should extend the `Actor` class and you would get a working actor. So I tried to guess how can this be done and imagined that each `Actor` has life-cycle, something like wait asynchronously for a message queue, then process message and then go to start.

That was a totally false assumption. Although the documentation says "actor life-cycle" it does not mean `Actor` life-cycle. *Actor* mentioned is a conception rather than an actual object implementing the `Actor` class. The object resides passively in the java heap.

To breathe life into the conception, coordinated work involving a bunch of real workers is needed. And the heart of it is a *dispatcher*. It holds all actors, threads, and messages. And when the resources become available and there are messages available for processing the *dispatcher* activates. It takes an appropriate `Actor` object, wraps its receive method in runnable, and passes it to a spare thread. So there is no life-cycle for the object only occasional method calls from the actor system.

When you think of it, it makes much more sense than the scheme I assumed earlier. But it was hard for me to deduce it from available documentation. It was written by seasoned concurrency programmers. The distinguish holding the actor class from *actor* conception behind it. They know that *dispatcher* for an actor system is like a task scheduler for an OS. So they quickly get to the point and describe various flavors and realization of the conception assumed to be familiar to everyone.

But that is not so easy for a newbie. He has no acquaintance of the *dispatcher pattern* in the actor systems context. I tried to google "dispatcher pattern" and it showed definitions non-relevant to the actor system.

I've found easily [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), multi-dispatch, and other OOP topics. I've found something similar to Akka's routers [message dispatcher](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageDispatcher.html). There is probably a decent description for actor message dispatchers but it not so easy to find.

I hope I've cleared the misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks for explaning, I had the same experience

Answer (score 5):

On 'I was looking into something more like say you are given a thread pool of 10 threads and 50 actors spun off of it, how are so many actors handled by a batch of 10 threads?'

The exact behavior depends on the dispatcher and configuration. However, most dispatchers do basically something like this:

- Select an actor which has a non-empty mailbox
- That 'actor' is then dispatched to run on the executor
- Where messages are dequed and processed.

  - When possible, a few messages are dequed and processed one after another
  - After processing some messages (or none left), another actor is picked, to prevent starvation. ([throughput parameter](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html))
- Rise and repeat

Answer (score 2):

You can find relevant information in the [akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/dispatchers.html) which is pretty complete as far as thing goes.

Essentially you can select/define dispatchers and assign actors to them through configuration (via files or code).

Each dispatcher implementation is then based on some sort of executor.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I was looking into something more like say you are given a thread pool of 10 threads and 50 actors spun off of it, how are so many actors handled by a batch of 10 threads? Will looking more at ExecutorService help?

Comment: probably you could have detailed answers on the [akka user list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/akka-user)