# What is the best way of setting nr-of-instances in Akka router

Tags: scala, akka

I am using akka router for creating actors. what is the best way to set  nr-of-instances ? my actor only purpose is insert data to the db so I want to have as many running in parallel actors as I can. is that just an arbitrary number ? what is the maximum ?

this is how the router is configured :

```
akka {
  actor{
    deployment {
      /Master/router9 {
          router = smallest-mailbox-pool
          nr-of-instances = ??? 

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer might give you a better idea of how actors relate to threads: [How are akka actors implemented on underlying threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673206/how-are-akka-actors-implemented-on-underlying-threads?answertab=active#tab-top)

As more actors are created the JVM heap will grow larger, but I do not think there is any hard maximum for the number of routees. I think choosing the number of instances should be made based on your own testing. The number of threads you have available and how often the threads are idle may inform your decision.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is not a real maximum beyond what the capabilities of your machine are and how many other things you are running. If you have the resources to run 10m of them you can. However, if you are trying to run a lot of actors I would say that you probably either have a blocking problem that is significant or you dont understand how the actors work with the pool.

An actor deployed doesn't hold a thread like the old thread pool executor pattern. It only uses a thread when it is processing a message and then surrenders the thread back to the dispatcher when the message is processed. In this way the dispatcher re-uses the threads. Therefore the configuration of the number of actors in the pool will depend upon whether you can get the bandwidth out of the actors. If you have too few the messages will start backing up in the inbox, if you have too many you could have been using those resources for something else. You will be surprised at how few actors you need to satisfy what you were doing before with mutlithreaded executors.

Now if you have long running processes in those actors the you should consider offloading those processes to actors that exist for the sole purpose of dealing with that long running process. Lets say, for example, your actors will be mostly handling mundane database operations that take a few milliseconds to complete but a couple of messages you send invoke an analytical database search that can take 10 to 30 seconds to return. In computing terms this is an eternity. So for those processes you would be better off having your database actor fork off a Per-Task Actor. This is an actor that exists only to service a particular request then stops itself after sending back the response. The general process is:

```
context.actorOf(Props(classOf[PerTaskActor], sender(), message)
```

This will create a new child actor of this actor. If you want to create as a top level actor then call system.actorOf( ... ). The constructor looks like:

```
class PerTaskActor(replyTo: ActorRef, msg: MyLongProcessMessage) {
 // .... 
}
```

Then inside the actor we run the process and when done:

```
replyTo.tell(result)
context.stop(self)
```

In this manner your long running tasks are offloaded. I would recommend you dont make these actors children of fragile actors that can crash a lot because if the parent actor crashes, it takes down all children with it. You might want a special parent actor(rather than the routed actor) for these.